# How do I make a while true loop only start the program/minecraft server again if it closes or crashes?

Tags: linux, while-loop, server, minecraft, cpu-usage

Hi I am running a Minecraft server with a restart plugin but it requires the program to restart itself, so I used a While true sleep 5 loop, and it seems to work fine but after some time it just starts opening again and again and there by it at some point gets to use 100% cpu usage all the time.

How do I make it not start the program again before the server closes or crashes?

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
java -Xms1G -Xmx6G -jar server.jar
sleep 5
done
```

Since sleep is set to 5 after it keeps opening again and again I see that is says failed to start the minecraft server every 5 secs but it is already running, and I want it to only run the while loop if the program is not running.

Comment: Sounds like the question you really want to ask is, "how to determine within a bash script if Minecraft is already running".

Comment: @DanR Yes that is correct, The problem was that after something like 6-7 hours it would begin to keep running the script which it failed and that caused it to use 100% cpu.

Comment: I should probably change the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) with the `-f` flag you can search for a running process with some arguments. You can use this to check if a server is already running.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    if ! pgrep -f server.jar
    then
        java -Xms1G -Xmx6G -jar server.jar
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Ofir I will see if it works, I will come back Tomorrow

Comment: It works many thanks @Ofir, now it does not use 100% cpu, but after a server restart the terminal window does not follow the minecraft server log and chat, but instead it shows the PID ID of the program job and prints it every 5 sec. Ex it prints 38906 until it restarts again and then goes to printing 61099 down the terminal and so on.

I think it does it because it checks if it is running am I right, and thereby it should not be a problem that it shows the PID ID every 5 sec, other than the terminal not matching the Minecraft server log and chat. Again Thanks.